# Least squares with multiple constraints

Tags: r, optimization, least-squares, lasso, constrained-regression

I work with a regression with ARMA errors and I want to use LASSO to shrink the coefficients and select my variables. This topic is discussed in the article [Wu et al. (2012)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375812000948).
So, the problem I have to minimize is:

$$
L(\xi)=||Y-X\xi||^2+\lambda_1\sum_{i=1}^{d}\frac{|\beta_i|}{|\beta_{i}^{OLS}|}+\lambda_2\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{|\phi_i|}{|\phi_{i}^{OLS}|}+\lambda_3\sum_{i=1}^{q}\frac{|\theta_i|}{|\theta_{i}^{OLS}|}
$$
where: $\xi=[\beta,\phi,\theta]$ and $\xi^{OLS}=[\beta^{OLS},\phi^{OLS},\theta^{OLS}]$ is the least squares estimate.

Do you know if there is a function in R that can solve this minimization? Something similar with glmnet / l1ce / lars, but with multiple constraints on the parameters?

Comment: This can be done with `glmnet` where you manually supply the tuning parameters with the `penalty.factor` argument.